How do I change font size of Cosmos OS programmatically?
I'd been trying everything to make the font size bigger. Is it even possible with the default font? If yes, can you tell me how?
This is how I tried to make it work:
public static PCScreenFont MenuFont = new PCScreenFont(32, 16, new byte[4096], new List<UnicodeMapping>());

Although I asked ChatGPT to help me, nothing works.
